# Best native alternative to regexp_replace

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

I have a string in the following format:-

Company_1 > Company_2 (100% name change) > Company_3 (Pre-2001) (100% merger) > Company_4 (TRUCK, 36% planner)

I currently use regexp_replace to remove any case of brackets containing a percentage, so ending up with the following

Company_1 > Company_2 > Company_3 (Pre-2001) > Company_4

The problem is this runs against a table containing 50m rows, and regexp_replace is not proving efficient.  Is there a way of rewriting this in sql, or worst case putting it into a sql function.

Comment: A regexp seems like the best approach here.

Comment: How often are you trying to read and process every row of a 50 million row table?  If you're doing it once, I'd assume that you wouldn't care too much if it took a few seconds so I'm assuming you're doing it at least somewhat frequently.  If you're trying to read 50 million rows frequently, I'd suggest that the better approach would be to find a way to more efficiently identify the rows that actually need to be processed rather than improving the efficiency of the processing.

Comment: I'd be looking to do this processing only for the rows that are changing (via a trigger, a timestamp, or some other key).  Or creating an index that identifies the rows that need to be processed.  Potentially a function-based index (or an index on a computed column) with a regexp_like or regexp_count of whatever regular expression you're looking for.

Comment: 50 millions still is not a big number, so regexp should be fine. Do you mind to share the code have you been using here?